# The usefulness of some bits in TIMSK register

Tags: avr

There are things in `TIMSK` Register that confused me. According to the datasheet regarding Atmega32:

> When the TOIE0 bit is written to one, and the I-bit in the Status Register is set (one), the Timer/Counter0 Overflow interrupt is enabled.

And then it says that the corresponding interrupt, namely `TOV0`, in `TIFR` register is executed.

What's the need for `TOIE0` bit at all? If it's being enabled by hardware and I can't disable it (well, I might by writing a logic 1 to it but for what reason/outcome?) then why was it ever built into the register? The same story holds for other bits such as `OCIE0` in `TIMSK` register and its corresponding flag in `TIFR` register, `OCF0`. I haven't studied other bits in `TIMSK` register but for now the first two bits have confused me.

Comment: Judging this and your previous questions, it looks like you are mixing interrupts and the flags triggering them.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If you look at my previous question I never enabled TOIE0 bit but still able to keep track of TOV0. The datasheet also says that it's initially zero.  So why ever was an overflow flag fired while I never enabled TOIE0?

Comment: Setting a flag in the status register is *not* an interrupt. An interrupt *triggered* by this flag can be enabled or disabled. These are the things you are mixing up. `TOV0` is a flag. An interrupt can be triggered by it if `TOIE0` is set.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But TOIE0 was initially disabled so this flag must not trigger any interrupt. This is what confuses me.

Comment: So it is not triggering it. Do you observe it is triggered when it is disabled?

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, just look at my last question. I never changed its default value which is zero. However, I was able to toggle the led using this flag, which was triggering every time an overflow occurred. So it seems that TOIE0 wasn't disabled?

Comment: Again. You have *not used any interrupt*. You have polled the flag. Do you understand what interrupt is? Interrupt is a *process*. And the status flag is the *trigger* of this process. The enable bit is "connecting" the trigger to the process.

Answer (score 2):

That bit of the TIMSK register controls whether the **Timer/Counter 0 overflow interrupt** will be enabled or not. It is essential if you are going to code a interrupt service routine (ISR) for TC0, then you need a `1` in this bit to enable the overflow interrupt to be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The Interrupt Enable bits tell when you want to receive an interrupt.

Typical configurations:

1. No interrupt needed. The application just leaves the timer running, and looks at the counter value whenever something else happens, to find out how long it took. Then, all IE bits are zero.
2. Measuring long intervals. You are still only interested in how long something took, but this can be a long time, and you expect the counter to overflow. Then, you enable the `TOIE0` bit, and your interrupt handler implements the higher-order bits in the counter in software.
3. Measuring exact intervals. You start the timer, set up a comparison value, then enable `OCIE0` and the auto-reset flag. You receive an interrupt every time the comparator matches, and the timer is restarted, so you have a well-defined interval between interrupts.
4. PWM. You set both `TOIE0` and `OCIE0`, then you get interrupts when the counter matches the comparison value, and when it overflows. When the counter matches, you turn the output off, when the overflow happens, you turn it on.